# Regex Comma Separated Emails

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get this Regex statement to work

`^([_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})+(\s?[,]\s?|$))+$`

for a string of comma separated emails in a `textbox` using `jQuery('#textbox').val();` which passes the values into the Regex statement to find errors for a string like:

`"test@test.com, test1@test.com,test2@test.com"`

But for some reason it is returning an error. I tried running it through http://regexpal.com/ but i'm unsure ?

**NB:** This is just a basic client-side test. I validate emails via the `MailClass` on the server-side using .NET4.0 - so don't jump down my throat re-this. The aim here is to eliminate simple errors.

**Escaped Version:**

`^([_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,3})+(\\s?[,]\\s?|$))+$`

Comment: why don't you just split the string with `split(',')` and then run each email through a simpler regex?

Comment: @Pablo - thanks for the response. Only the `+(\s?[,]\s?|$)` relates to comma seperated values - the rest is email validation. Mean even if I split the emails - I'd still be running it via this anyway ?

Comment: Can you add the code that uses the regular expression?  Your expression works in .net and I don't see anything that looks invalid for javascript as long as it's used and escaped correctly.

Comment: @agent-j - i'm not seeing an error - the problem is that the Regex keeps returning the errorMessage for the above string and it doesn't make sense ? i.e. wanted someone to confirm it's not incorrect ?

Comment: @agent-j - added the escaped version also ?

Comment: try simplifying the regex to `test`.  This will make sure there's not something going on in the bowels.  If it still doesn't match, then you know it's not the regex.

Comment: There's a lot of things you can simplify in the regex to cut down on possible issues. As @Pablo said, perhaps split it beforehand; consider that you're going to have to split it anyways, so you're not doing any extra work, just changing the order of it to simplify your validation. Then there's the `[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*` which occurs twice in your regex. It looks fine to me, but an easier way of saying the same thing would be `[\w-][\w.-]*` -- the more you can simplify the regex, the easier it's going to be to identify issues. (I also assume you're running this as case-insensitive?)

Comment: Trying to do way too much with regular expressions, take Pablo's hint and split it first, then worry about whatever problem. Right now the regex is so big, I am not not even going to give it a try. When you ask a question, you want to create a reduction of a problem, not just a big blob that doesn't work

Comment: @JuanMendes @GregJackson - care to suggest a better regex :) ?

Comment: The suggestion is to rewrite the question without trying to use the regular expression to split the commas. It's Pablo's suggestion, btw. Call split on the whole string, then run the regex against each email, not the whole list.

Comment: @JuanMendes - sure, thanks - if you can add that as a suggestion and a "simplier" regex for emails - i'll select it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greatly simplify things by first splitting on commas, as Pablo said, then repeatedly applying the regex to validate each individual email. You can also then point out the one that's bad -- but there's a big caveat to that.

Take a look at the regex in the article [Comparing E-mail Address Validating Regular Expressions](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php). There's another even better regex that I couldn't find just now, but the point is a correct regex for checking email is incredibly complicated, because the rules for a valid email address as specified in the RFC are incredibly complicated.

In yours, this part `(\.[a-z]{2,3})+` jumped out at me; the two-or-three-letters group `{2,3}` I often see as an attempt to validate the top-level domain, but (1) your regex allows one *or more* of these groups and (2) you will exclude valid email addresses from domains such as `.info` or `.museum`  (Many sites reject my `.us` address because *they* thought only 3 letter domains were legal.)

My advice to reject seriously invalid addresses, while leaving the final validation to the server, is to allow basically (anything)@(anything).(anything) -- check only for an "at" and a "dot", and of course allow multiple dots.

EDIT: Example for "simple" regex

`[^@]+@[^.]+(\.[^.]+)+`

This matches

- test@test.com
- test1@test.com
- test2@test.com
- foo@bar.baz.co.uk
- myname@modern.museum

And doesn't match `foo@this....that`

Note: Even this will reject some valid email addresses, because *anything* is allowed on the left of the `@` - even another `@` - if it's all escaped properly. But I've never seen that in 25 years of using email in Real Life.

Comment: great simple :) So I've used the splitter instead, validated with this simplier version and still validate with ASP.NET on the server-side :) happy days!